# Incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'char* [50]

Tags: c++, punteros

Necesito crear un programa en el que se puedan cargar los datos de los alumnos, sacar el promedio de todas las notas y mostrar en pantalla los datos de los usuarios con nota superior a 7.

Entiendo que el problema está en que no puedo igualar un `char *` con un `int`, sin embargo no encuentro la solución, ya que si cambio a nota por `char` ya no puedo crear el `if (alumno.nota >= 7)`.

A menos de que con alguna biblioteca pueda convertir el int en un char antes del pasaje no se me ocurre otra solución.

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <cstring>
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    /*Se leen datos de notas obtenidas por los alumnos de una cátedra y se
    desea informar
    − el promedio de las notas obtenidas por los alumnos
    − el nombre, tipo y número de documento y número de legajo
    (padrón) de los alumnos que hayan aprobado con nota igual o mayor
    que siete.
    − Los datos del/los alumnos con peor nota.
    La secuencia finaliza con el alumno Wolf Roberto que debe ser
    procesado*/
    
    using namespace std;
    
    struct notas
    {
        char nombre[50];
        char tipodoc[50];
        int DNI;
        int Legajo;
        int nota;
        char aprobo[30];
    };
    
    void estructura_notas(float &promnota, char *mejoresalumnos[][4][50], int &cantalum)
    {
        int i=0;
        int peornota;
        notas alumno;
        do
        {
            setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");
            cout << "Ingrese el nombre: ";
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(alumno.nombre);
            cout << "Ingrese el tipo de DOC: ";
            fflush(stdin);
            gets (alumno.tipodoc);
            cout << "Ingrese el numero de DNI: ";
            cin >> alumno.DNI;
            cout << "Ingrese el legajo: ";
            cin >> alumno.Legajo;
            cout << "Ingrese la nota: ";
            cin >> alumno.nota;
            promnota = alumno.nota+promnota;
            cout << "Ingrese si aprobo: ";
            fflush(stdin);
            gets (alumno.aprobo);
            if (alumno.nota >= 7)
            {
                mejoresalumnos[i][0][50] = alumno.nombre;
                mejoresalumnos[i][1][50] = alumno.tipodoc;
                mejoresalumnos[i][2] = alumno.DNI;
                mejoresalumnos[i][3] = alumno.Legajo;
                mejoresalumnos[i][4] = alumno.nota;
                i++;
            }
        }while(strcmp(alumno.nombre,"Wolf Roman"));
        cantalum = i;
        return;
    }
    
    
    
    int main()
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");
        char *mejoresalumnos[][4][50];
        float promnota;
        int cantalum;
        notas alumno;
        estructura_notas(promnota, mejoresalumnos, cantalum);
        cout << "El promedio de todas las notas es: " << promnota/2 << endl;
        for (int i; i<=cantalum; i++)
        {
            cout << "\n  NOMBRE  " << "||" << "  TIPODOC  " << "||" << "  DNI  " << "||" << "  LEGAJO  " << "||" << "  NOTA  " << endl;
            cout << mejoresalumnos[i][0] << "||" << mejoresalumnos[i][1] << "||" << mejoresalumnos[i][2] << "||" << mejoresalumnos[i][3];
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenias muchos errores, claro que hay maneras de convertir de `int` a `char`.

Pero en tu caso lo que estabas haciendo no era la mejor ejecución para resolver el problema, si lo que tienes es un `struct` con tipos de datos definidos, por que no usar mejor el mismo tipo `struct` para devolver los usuarios con promedio menor a 7 ?.

Ahí puse como maximo 20 alumnos con peor nota, pero si quieres que sea dinámico te recomiendo usar primero [malloc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) y despues [realloc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm) si quieres modificar el sizeof.

Y ten en cuenta que el promedio grupal, se calcula con la suma total de todas las notas entre el numero de alumnos.

También te recomiendo que repasases [punteros](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointers.htm).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>

/*Se leen datos de notas obtenidas por los alumnos de una cátedra y se
desea informar
− el promedio de las notas obtenidas por los alumnos
− el nombre, tipo y número de documento y número de legajo
(padrón) de los alumnos que hayan aprobado con nota igual o mayor
que siete.
− Los datos del/los alumnos con peor nota.
La secuencia finaliza con el alumno Wolf Roberto que debe ser
procesado*/

using namespace std;

struct notas
{
    char nombre[50];
    char tipodoc[50];
    int DNI;
    int Legajo;
    int nota;
    char aprobo[30];
};

int estructura_notas(float *promnota, notas* alumnosAprobados)
{
    int i=0;
    int peornota;
    notas alumno;
    do
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");
        cout << "Ingrese el nombre: ";
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(alumno.nombre);
        cout << "Ingrese el tipo de DOC: ";
        fflush(stdin);
        gets (alumno.tipodoc);
        cout << "Ingrese el numero de DNI: ";
        cin >> alumno.DNI;
        cout << "Ingrese el legajo: ";
        cin >> alumno.Legajo;
        cout << "Ingrese la nota: ";
        cin >> alumno.nota;
        *promnota = (*promnota)+alumno.nota;
        cout << "Ingrese si aprobo: ";
        fflush(stdin);
        gets (alumno.aprobo);
        if (alumno.nota >= 7)
        {
            strcpy(alumnosAprobados[i].nombre,alumno.nombre);
            strcpy(alumnosAprobados[i].tipodoc, alumno.tipodoc);
            alumnosAprobados[i].DNI = alumno.DNI;
            alumnosAprobados[i].Legajo = alumno.Legajo;
            alumnosAprobados[i].nota = alumno.nota;
            i++;
        }
    }while(strcmp(alumno.nombre,"Wolf Roman"));
    return i;
}



int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");
    float promnota = 0;
    notas alumnosAprobados[20];
    int cantalum = estructura_notas(&promnota, alumnosAprobados);
    cout << "El promedio de todas las notas es: " << (promnota/cantalum)<< endl;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < cantalum; i++)
    {
        cout << "\n  NOMBRE  " << "||" << "  TIPODOC  " << "||" << "  DNI  " << "||" << "  LEGAJO  " << "||" << "  NOTA  " << endl;
        cout << alumnosAprobados[i].nombre << "||" << alumnosAprobados[i].tipodoc << "||" << alumnosAprobados[i].DNI << "||" << alumnosAprobados[i].nota;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias maestro, ahora me pongo a repasar, el tema es q ando corto de tiempo pq mañana tengo parcial jajajajajja, pero por temas externos no tuve tiempo para estudiar tanto, si, soy un pelotudo, lo se jajajajaja, pero bueno, te agradezco, la verdad me habia olvidado de el strcpy, nuevamente muchas gracias.

Comment: -1 por proponer el uso de `malloc` y `realloc` entre otras funciones de C cuando la solución se escribe en C++, así como por usar `strcpy` en lugar de `strncpy` cuando la longitud máxima del búffer está definida.